# Calling getActivity() inside an AsyncTask safely

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

My app keeps crashing when I leave it running in the background and then go back to having the app on screen. I believe it has something to do with my AsyncTask that is running in onResume(). In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17829562/3851567) on one of the comments the guy says to "keep trace of an instance of the activity and make the async task wait for it to be not null." So how exactly do I make it wait until it's not null?

And in general, what is the safest way to refer to an activity when you have an AsyncTask running inside a Fragment that will work during activity/fragment lifecycle changes?

Comment: pass activity to asynctask , in this scenario your activity will not be garbage collected untill unless it your async task get completed.

Comment: @dex so you're implying not to call getActivity() at all in an AsyncTask but rather pass in a reference of the activity to the AsyncTask? And this automatically keeps the activity from being garbage collected?

Comment: Just don't use an AsyncTask. Use a Loader instead (AsyncTaskLoader is a good starting point) which is designed to handle configuration changes appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can typecast getactivity() with the activity containing that fragment in on create of fragment and make ***mActivity*** global variable.

```
MainActivity mActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
```

You can use that variable further in Asynctask and can further check whether the activity got finished (don't check for null)

```
mActivity.isFinished();
```

Answer (score 0):

Never count on an `Activity` running (or even existing) while in the background or back stack.  Putting an `AsyncTask` in a retained `Fragment` is a good way to keep the task running across configuration changes (e.g., device rotation) but not when the activity is in the background.  Anything that's supposed to keep running in the background belongs in a `Service`.

Comment: I'm not running anything that will continuously be running in a background thread so using a Service is not my concern. I just want the data displaying in the fragment to be updated when `onResume()` is called, so when the user comes back to the app, it loads the most recent data. This data is retrieved through an AsyncTask. It is contained within a retained Fragment, but I also need to be grabbing data that is on the hosting activity, hence why I'm using getActivity() in the AsynctTask.

Answer (score -1):

It's not recommended. If you need to access your activity inside the AsyncTask, then the best way is to create an interface, make your activity implement this interface and pass the activity instance on the AsyncTask constructor. Your AsyncTask will need a property of the interface type. So, you can call the methods implemented on the activity by this interface

Comment: Even then, you risk a memory leak (since task is still holding a reference to the Activity).